# Invariant violation - React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string

Tags: javascript

I tried to create a react component library for company intern usage.
After building it with webpack on our gitlab repo, I tried to use it in an project to test it. I added reference to package.json, imported one component from library to a component, and builded the app. All worked, but when I tried to run the app, I received the next error:

React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Here is my component library's webpack.config.js code:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        'whatwg-fetch'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build/lib'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        library: '',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass- 
                loader']
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In package.json I have:

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"build-dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack --mode=development",
"build": "npm install && NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode=production",
"dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --hot --mode=development --progress"
},
```

I used npm run build to publish the library.

One of my component looks like:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
...

class Button extends Component {
...

render() {
    return (
        <button
            className={cx('defaultButton', size, skin, textAlign, { disabled, readOnly }, className)}
            onClick={this.onClickHandler}
            onMouseDown={this.props.onMouseDown}
            style={buttonStyles}
            type={type}
        >
            {children}
            {premiumBadge}
        </button>
        );
    }
}

Button.propTypes = {
...

}
Button.defaultProps = {
...
};

export default Button;
```

Finally my index.js is :

```
import Button from './components/Button'

export {
    Button
}
```

In another app I added the reference to the package.json as dependency

```
"dependencies" : {
...
    "components": "git+https://install:---key---@repo",
...
```

Package appears in node_modules, but at runtime, if I include Button in component, I had the above error.

```
import { Button } from 'components/build/lib/index';

class Whatever extends Component {
... 
render() {
    const { useOurLogo } = this.props;
    const { logo, saveMessage, displayLoader } = this.state;
    const { errorMessage } = saveMessage;

    return (
        <div className={styles.main}>
            <Button skin="black" />
            <LoaderHover size="none" display={displayLoader} />
```

Comment: You're mixing default imports with named exports, which seems errorprone. I'd stick to named imports/exports.

Comment: Where I mixed ? I used default export in component, after that I used default import in main index.js file. Here I used named export for component. Then I use also named import in app, where I included the library.